# Join con 5 tablas en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo 5 tablas que tienen transacciones, entre las columna de cada tabla esta "Date" que es la fecha de la transacción.

Necesito hacer un select donde pueda comprar las 5 tablas y ver si tiene transacción para un rango de fecha predeterminada.

Comment: translate your question into spanish, otherwise it will be closed

Comment: Discúlpame Alfredo, como puedo editar la pregunta que ya hice?

Comment: dale click en editar, pon todo en español y ya con eso basta

Comment: Listo, lo encontré. Gracias.

Comment: Cuál es la llave de comparación de las tablas?

Comment: No es un campo llave, pero se pueden relacionar por el campo "unit".

Comment: El registro fecha está en todas las tablas y tienes que verificarlo en todas ellas?

Comment: Correcto. Así es.

Answer (score 0):

Con nombres supuestos, y asumiendo que contienen fk entre sí:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1 T1
INNER JOIN tabla2 T2 ON T1.unit = T2.unit
INNER JOIN tabla3 T3 ON T2.unit = T3.unit
...
WHERE T1.DATE BETWEEN @fecha1 AND @fecha2
AND T2.DATE BETWEEN @fecha1 AND @fecha2
...
AND T5.DATE BETWEEN @fecha1 AND @fecha2
```

Comment: Y si no tengo FK igual puede funcionar. Por otro lado, no quiero desplegar todo (*) solo quiero que traiga la fecha.

Comment: Los campos de ligue pueden ser cualquiera, siempre y cuando sean iguales, ahora, es recomendable que estén indexados. Y si quieres traer ejemplo TODO de la tabla1 usas ´T1.*´ y para valores específicos ´T5.DATE´.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con `INNER JOIN` y condicionales solo debes indicar en el `JOIN` que el campo este entre tu rango de fecha, el `WHERE` se usaría si ninguna de las tablas dependen de otra mediante una `KEY`. Estoy asumiendo que la `TABLA1` es la tabla principal que contiene la `PRIMARY KEY` para las otras tablas en caso contrario aplica el `WHERE`:

```
SELECT 
    A.Date,
    B.Date,
    C.Date,
    D.Date,
    E.Date
FROM TABLA1 A
INNER JOIN TABLA2 B ON A.unit = B.unit AND B.Date BETWEEN @FECHA_INICIO AND @FECHA_FIN
INNER JOIN TABLA3 C ON A.unit = C.unit AND C.Date BETWEEN @FECHA_INICIO AND @FECHA_FIN
INNER JOIN TABLA4 D ON A.unit = D.unit AND D.Date BETWEEN @FECHA_INICIO AND @FECHA_FIN
INNER JOIN TABLA5 E ON A.unit = E.unit AND E.Date BETWEEN @FECHA_INICIO AND @FECHA_FIN
--WHERE A.Date BETWEEN @FECHA_INICIO AND @FECHA_FIN
```